# Is there any way to add RichTextBox to C# Xamarin project for Android?

Tags: c#, android, windows, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a problem translating a C# project that I created for Windows, to Android Xamarin. I have searched the web to find any solution about RichTextBox and other functions and components that I used for building the Windows version program but I couldn't find any good solution except one topic [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29990/create-rich-textbox-in-xamarin-droid) but it didn't help me.
If there is no way to add something like a richtextbox, is there any other textbox that supports .Lines so I can get the correct line number?

Here is a part of my code:

```
        private void ThreadTask1()
    {
        string link = "http://example.com/music-today.php";
        int TimeToWait = 300;
        int check_ID = 0;

        string ParsedResult = null;

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = null;
        HtmlWeb web1 = new HtmlWeb();

        while (true) {

            ParsedResult = "";
            RichTextBox1.Clear(); 
            RichTextBox2.Clear(); 

            web1.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)";
            web1.UsingCache = false;
            web1.UseCookies = true;

            doc = web1.Load(link);

            HtmlNode div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='latest-song14']"); 

            if ((div != null)) {
                ParsedResult = div.InnerText.Trim();
                RichTextBox1.Text = ParsedResult;
                RichTextBox2.Text = RichTextBox1.Lines[0];

                if (!RichTextBox2.Text.Contains("dj")) {
                    Sound vol = new Sound("nircmdc.exe");
                    vol.setVol(40);

                    while (true) {
                        MyMusicInformer.My.MyProject.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\\Windows\\media\\Alarm01.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(700);
                        MyMusicInformer.My.MyProject.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\\Windows\\media\\Alarm01.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(700);
                        MyMusicInformer.My.MyProject.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\\Windows\\media\\Alarm01.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    }
                } else {
                    check_ID = check_ID + 1;
                    RichTextBox2.Text = "No new song yet. Try (" + check_ID.ToString() + ")";
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeToWait * 1000);
        }
    }


    private Thread trd1;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        trd1 = new Thread(ThreadTask1);
        trd1.IsBackground = true;
        trd1.Start();
    }
```

I only want to be able to be informed when there is a new song update. In Visual Studio I can only see the "Multiline Text" option but it can't solve my problem.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Xamarin.Forms.Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Editor?view=xamarin-forms) control? I'm sure that it can help you.